# Does Gus have psychic powers?

Tags: sweet-tooth

When Gus falls asleep in the field of purple flowers, he sees a vision of his father, who urges him to continue on his journey. This could be a regular hallucination provoked by the flowers, or a dream that he had while unconscious, but he also sees a vision of General Abbot with glowing flames for eyes, addressing him by name and saying that he will see him soon. At this point, Gus does not seem to have either met or seen General Abbot.

Further, Gus shows the ability to calm a tiger simply by speaking to it. This does not seem to be related to him being a deer—in fact, quite the contrary, since tigers should if anything want to eat deer. He also seems to attract deer to  him, although this could be attributed to something slightly more mundane, such as him smelling like a deer.

Does Gus, in addition to his deer-related abilities (acute senses, primarily), have mental powers?